# How can I publish my software to public linux repos to be available with "apt" installers etc

Tags: linux, package, installation, apt

I have developed (free) software, more precisely, a development environment or a code editor called "Lines". On the web I have set up installation packages for Windows and Linux, but I would like the application to be available as an "apt" package on linux systems. The easiest way to do this (and not get tired) is?

By the way, software and installation packages are available at https://creatixbih.com/lines/
Thank you.

Since I'm not really a "linux" guru, I've been trying to find an automated solution.

Comment: [How to get my software into Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/q/16446), [How do I create a PPA?](https://askubuntu.com/q/71510), [Packaging/PPA/InstallingSoftware](https://help.launchpad.net/Packaging/PPA/InstallingSoftware), etc.

Comment: Very very nice editor BTW!

Answer (score 23, accepted):

First you need to create a DEB package, you can read more about it [here](https://wiki.debian.org/HowToPackageForDebian).

The easiest way to get your package into huge repositories would be to submit your package to Debian, where Ubuntu is based off. A detailed explanation can be found [here](https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/distribute-deb/distribute-deb.html).

Another good method would be to host your OWN apt repository which is being explained [here](https://wiki.debian.org/DebianRepository/Setup?action=show&redirect=HowToSetupADebianRepository)

Comment: The link for submitting a package to Debian is a dead link now.

Comment: [This Unix SE answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/620698/469135) explains the process and the caveats as well. You might not want to publish to Debian, depending on your needs.

Comment: While these links may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the links for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.